# Using AMPScript to Output an event location based on a Event DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a master DE that has all my marketing database, within this DE each person has preferred store.

We are running a series of event based on their preferred store

I have almost no experience with AMPScript however understand i can use a AMPScript to reference a preferred store name from my master DE to pull data from a event data Ext matching on the preferred store in the event DE

My Preferred Store DE will has the following fields:

- Preferred_Store
- Branch_Name
- EventLocation
- Event Date
- Event Time

My Master DE has:

- First Name
- Last Name
- EMail
- Mobile
- Address
- Preferred Store

I need the AMPScript to lookup preferred store name on the Master DE for a individual, and output the Event data.

We will need to output all fields into a table form the Event DE

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any of the Lookup functions available with AMPScript (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the plethora of [**lookuprows() and lookuporderedrows()**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bampscript%5D%20lookuprows%20OR%20lookupOrderedRows%20is%3Aanswer) examples here on SFSE, here's [**an example from The AMPscript Guide**](https://ampscript.guide/book/?section=lookuprows):

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @region, @i

set @region = AttributeValue("Region") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @region = "North" /* or a literal value */
set @rows = LookupRows("LoyaltyMembers","region", @region)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

output(concat("region: ", @region))

if @rowCount > 0 then
  for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    var @emailAddress, @firstName, @rank
    set @row = row(@rows, @i) /* get row based on counter */
    set @firstName = field(@row,"firstName")
    set @emailAddress = field(@row,"emailAddress")

    ]%%

    <br>Row %%=v(@i)=%%, firstName: %%=v(@firstName)=%%, emailAddress: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

I also have some variations [**here on my blog**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).